# Two approaches to the definition of a connection

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensor-products, tensors, vector-bundles, connections

A connection can be defined as a map $$D:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(E)\otimes\Gamma(T^*M)$$ satisfying the usual conditions or, equivalently,
$$F:\Gamma(TM)\otimes \Gamma(E)\to \Gamma(E).$$

My question is simple: how can I see the **equivalence** of these two definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s \in \Gamma(E)$ and $V \in \Gamma(TM)$, then the two notions are related by the equality $$D(s)(V) = F(V, s)$$ as elements in $\Gamma(E)$.

Comment: Were there used some of the conditions from the definition of a connection in your answer?

Comment: @user122424: No.